# jupyter notebook + python で、プロセス処理時間のウォーターフォール図のようなものを図示したい

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Google Chrome で DevConsole を開くと、 処理時間のウォーターフォール図が取得可能です。

[image: DevConsole Waterfall on Chrome]

今、 jupyter notebook 上で、諸々の開始時刻と終了時刻からなるイベントデータを取得していて、それを、この Chrome のウォーターフォール図のような形で図示したいと考えました。

これを実現するにあたって、よく使われるライブラリなどはありますか？